# How can i login magmi

Tags: magento-1.9, login, magmi

How can i login magmi, am copy of the magmi folder into magento root folder, then go to http://www.------.com/magmi/web/magmi.php, they ask username and password

[image]

Comment: That's good, somebody added password protection with `.htaccess`. Otherwise your site would be an easy target for hackers, never leave magmi accessible from outside! Solution: ask for the password and enter it

Comment: I still believe the magmi web panel shouldn't be deployed at all, but we only use the data pump API

Answer (score 6):

The more recent version of Magmi uses the Magento admin authorization system to protect the Magmi admin panel.

Log in with your Magento admin username and password.

See [the Magmi code](https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/blob/master/magmi/inc/magmi_auth.php#L34-L39):

```
public function authenticate(){
    if (!$this->_hasDB) return ($this->user == 'magmi' && $this->pass == 'magmi');
    $tn=$this->tablename('admin_user');
    $result = $this->select("SELECT * FROM $tn WHERE username = ?",array($this->user))->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $this->validatePass($result['password'],$this->pass);
}
```

Comment: Actually am tried with my magento user name and password, but its not working,

Comment: which file i need to edit

Comment: could you help me to solve this

Comment: Didn't work me either. I tried username  `magmi` and password `magmi` as  in 
 the code and that worked.